# JQuery loader - Parallax site

Tags: jquery, html, loader

Is there a way to create a loader for a parallax site that waits until all dom elements are loader before triggering a function?

I have created a IOS version of a parallax site - all works fine - but as the site contains many large images the animation can be triggered before all images have loaded..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you lazy load the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it just like this:

```
$(function(){
   var $imgs = $('img');
   var cnt = $imgs.length;
   $imgs.load(function(){
       cnt--;
       if(cnt === 0)
          //load parallax here
   });
});
```